# Permission denied when creating a database

Tags: sql-server, restore

Currently, my local instance looks like this

[image: Database]

I want to restore my user database

I have tried restoring my database my rightclicking on Databases and also tried right clicking and doing it on system databases but I get this error

[image: Restore]

I also have the same permission error when trying to create a new empty database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a Windows admin, you may create a sysadmin login for yourself following the procedure documented here: [Connect to SQL Server when system administrators are locked out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15)

Here it is in batch file form to run (from an elevated command prompt), for a default instance:

```
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver 
sqlcmd -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

or for a named instance:

```
net stop mssql$sqlexpress 
net start mssql$sqlexpress /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssql$sqlexpress
net start mssql$sqlexpress
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

Note that if you create the login for `BUILTIN\administrators` and you've got [User Account Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-overview) enabled then you'll have to elevate to connect.  If you create a login for your individual account you won't need to elevate.

Comment: I tried this and still no luck. My account remains on public

Comment: Did you run SSMS from an elevated session?  Did you try replacing `BUILITIN\administrators` with your individual domain account?

Comment: After running your commands then running SSMS from an elevated Session.. it works! Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database (probably a backup file), then you need to restore the backup on your instance to have the "user" database there.

Otherwise, if you just want to have your own database, and if you have appropriate access to do so, then just run

> Create database [dbname];

and SQL will create a brand new empty database for you.

If you got lock outside of your SQL instance (you don't know the SA password and your account is not a member of the sysadmin server role), then you can refere to this post on how to regain access to your instance:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794079/windows-administrator-doesnt-have-permission-on-sql-server

Comment: How do I do the restore? What I have tried isn't working. So maybe I am doing something wrong. I have updated my original question to include how I tried restoring

Comment: Please give us some info about what you tried.
Usually, restoring is pretty strait foward... you can do it with the Gui or in TSQL with something like :
RESTORE DATABASE [dbname] FROM DISK=N'path_to_the_bak_file' (there is a lot of different option you can add but just this basic command should allow you to restore the backup)

Comment: What I was trying to do can be seen in the question

Comment: Say the backup file is on my C:, how can I restore it doing that command?

Comment: It seems you do not have enough permission.
Can you look in your login and let us know which access you have ?
You should have the same permission error if you type : Create database [test]; right ?

Comment: Yes I do. I am using windows authentication

Comment: Maybe I should sqitch to sql authentication. But not to sure how to convert over

Comment: You will still have a login in SQL (even if you are using Windows Auth.). It will either be your domain account, or a group that you are in. 
Also try the "create database [test]" statement to confirm that you do not have enough permission to create a DB

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. I dont have permission. And yeah I am logged in with my domain account

Comment: Then your problem is a permission issue.
In SSMS, expend "security" then "login" and look for your login. Right click on it and go into "properties". Look under "Server Role" and let us know which server role you have.

Comment: I just have public

Comment: But I am system admin in my domain so why is it like this? And what can I do to get the correct permission?

Comment: SQL does not longer gives SQL permission for system admin. 
Is this instance of SQL installed on a remote server or is it on you local PC ? if it's remote, who installed it (the SQL instance) ? (that person probably have the "sa" password or may have the "systemAdmin" server role on his own account and will be able to grant you the appropriate access)

Comment: I installed it on my own PC. The 'SA' user has a red x on it though

Comment: Ok, then let's presume that you are locked out of it... check this link it provide the "how to" to regain access on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794079/windows-administrator-doesnt-have-permission-on-sql-server